# Yoast SEO как получить значение reading time?

Tags: wordpress, yoast

Подскажите, как получать значения времени чтения поста из плагина [Yoast SEO](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) для нужного поста?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нашел, вот такую [документацию](https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/yoast/function/Indexable_Presentation::generate_estimated_reading_time_minutes) но не понимаю, как это применить если необходимо показывать время чтения для элементов списка категории, в цикле.

Answer (score 0):

Внутри цикла, где вам доступны данные поста (допустим, в переменной $post), добавьте такой код:

```
    // 200 is the approximate estimated number of words per minute across languages.
    $words_per_minute = 200;
    $words            = str_word_count( wp_strip_all_tags( $post->post_content ) );
    echo round( $words / $words_per_minute );
```

Comment: Что-то не считает.  Создал текст на 3500 слов согласно YoastSEO показывает, что 20 минут.  $words выдает значение 22. А если с отношением     echo round( $words / $words_per_minute );  то 0

Comment: Ну я не знаю, как у вас контент сделан. Если через какие-нибудь ACF блоки, то так не получится. Вам $words показывает, что у вас в контенте поста 22 слова. Поэтому и round( 22 / 200 ) = 0.

Comment: Я думал, что YoastSEO показывает только слова которые относяться к SEO-тексту стандартно вставляемого поста.(тот что гутенбергом редактируеться, и не захватывает доп. поля) Вот этотих слов я увеличил значения до 3500 слов. 3500/200 = 17.5 (по указаной формуле должно бы быть)  но показывает 20. $words - это точно получает значения параметра из YoastSEO фильтра ?